# Powershell holding a lock on a log file

Tags: powershell

I use `ADD-CONTENT` and `OUT-FILE` to write information to log files, and in order to simplify the amount of logs I have I'd like multiple instances of my script to be able to share log files. Is there any way to make sure that powershell doesn't hold a lock on those files when writing to them?

For example, I have a `SQLCMD` call that restores a database, which can take 20 minutes or so. During this time, it writes the output to a log file and thus maintains a lock on that file (so I can't write to it with other scripts).

Ideally I would like both processes to be able to write at the same time. Should I write a `test-file` function to see if the file is locked prior to writing? And if it is, sleep for x seconds and check again?

Comment: If you have multiple processes that need to all save data in some fashion you need a transactional method to do this. Any transactional DB is a valid option or writing to a custom or system event log works too.

Comment: Oh hey, write-eventlog seems to be what I want. More transactional and easier to read than log files I write and hide myself. If you put your comment as an answer I'd accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple processes writing to a file is pretty difficult to pull off safely. A better method is a transactional system. Many people use a transactional database for multiple processes to log to. Another good option is to write to a custom or system event log. This is also transactional and should avoid collisions.